# PHP $_server name and uri

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to get a piece of html to only show on the main page which is http://www.domain.com/ ... I wrote the code below but it doesn't work the HTML is showing regardless of the page, am I missing something

```
<?php
$hweb .= 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($hweb == 'http://www.domain.com/'):
?>          
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;">
                        <div style="float:left">



<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried an echo on `$hweb` to see what it makes of it? And `.=`? In this case `$hweb = ...;` makes more sense

Comment: yes i've echoed it and it's returned http://www.domain.com/ and when on another page http://www.domain.com/page.html so $hweb variable is working

Comment: (If) it returns domain.com, I found your problem. Missing slash. So you are matching `http://domain.com` to `http://domain.com/`. Oh wait, that's not your problem. Sorry

Comment: What does strcmp($hweb,'http://www.domain.com/') return? (Remove that semicolon that SO inserts into my code)

Answer (score 1):

First of all - please change

```
$hweb .= 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

into

```
$hweb = 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

$hweb may be initialized somewhere before.

Second:

As long as you request 'http://www.domain.com/somename.php' your if condition will never get executed. REQUEST_URI will always hold '/somename.php' except you use some url rewriting.

Third:
Make sure all calls go to 'http://www.domain.com' and not to 'http://domain.com'. Subdomain configurtaions sometimes are very complicated.

Comment: is there a way to detect the main page only then? I just want a piece of HTML coding to only load on the main page header and not all the other pages. The header.php file is universal throughout the site so I'm trying to isolate the piece of coding for the main page only

Comment: Usually you have to figure out some other variables to detect your main page. I can't tell without knowing your site/code/application.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of getting it wrong again..

Why not initialize a variable in the main file before including the header

```
<?php 
$mainfile = true;
?>
```

then in the header

```
<?php

if ($mainfile===true)
....
```

This way the main file can be called anything and be placed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
If the above code is written inside 'http://www.domain.com/index.php' file then it may work fine.
Solution 2:
else make sure that $hewb is set with null value earlier b4 this code so that  ".=" would not add extra value b4 'http...'.

Now

$hweb = '';

echo $hweb .= 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Answer (score -3):

That is because the the HTML is inline in the php file but outside of the PHP tags. You can simply echo the HTML inside the if.

```
if ($hweb == 'http://www.domain.com/')
{
    echo '<div style="margin:0 auto;">';
    echo '<div style="float:left">';
}
```

or if you have lots of HTML you could do it like this

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
<p>This HTML only be echoed </p>
</body>
</html>

<?php   
    $hweb .= 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    if ($hweb == 'http://www.domain.com/'):
    {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    else
    {
        ob_end_clean(); // Probably not needed
    }

?>
```

Comment: Just to elaborate, in general only code inside of the <?php tags is run by php everything outside is simply echoed to the browser. Your other alternative is to turn off output buffering with ob_start [link](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: is there a way to echo 50lines of html coding without having to type echo quotes for each line?

Comment: Yes see the example for ob_start. You turn off output buffering then write your HTML outside of the php tags. Then call ob_flush (inside php tags) link to ob_start in my comment above

Comment: @Duncan: HTML can be written as he did. Echo is not always necessary.

Comment: Well I'll be.. I didn't know about if ( .. ): I stand corrected!